# PHP Webshop cookie won't be saved

Tags: php, html, css

```
                if(isset($_POST["cartDelete"])){
                    $item_ID = $_POST["hidden_id"];

                    $cookie_data = stripslashes($_COOKIE['shopping_cart']);
                    $cart_data = json_decode($cookie_data, true);

                    unset($cart_data[$item_ID]);

                    $item_data = json_encode($cart_data);
                    setcookie('shopping_cart', $item_data, time() + (86400 * 30));

                    header("Location: cart");

                    print_r($cart_data);
                }
                if(isset($_POST["QTYedited"])){
                    $item_ID = $_POST["hidden_id"];
                    $item_QTY = $_POST["QTYedited"];

                    $cookie_data = stripslashes($_COOKIE['shopping_cart']);
                    $cart_data = json_decode($cookie_data, true);

                    $cart_data[$item_ID]["item_QTY"] = $item_QTY;

                    $item_data = json_encode($cart_data);
                    setcookie('shopping_cart', $item_data, time() + (86400 * 30));

                    header("Location: cart");
                }
```

I'm writing an webshop in php, but in this part the cookie somehow won't be saved. The whole fun is, with one item in the cart everything is working. The problem beginning with at least two items.

I've tried everything I knew. You can test the page with [webshop.abrisx.nhely.hu](http://webshop.abrisx.nhely.hu)

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that the cookie is `enabled` in your browser and note that some `illegal characters` will cause the cookie not to be stored,
Try calling `urlencode()` on your string before sending it to the cookie.

ex:

```
setcookie('shopping_cart', urlencode($item_data), time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
```

I think this will solve your problem.